# i want to make a group Hash by keys and add values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, sum, each

I have a Hash looks like this

```
arr = { 93=>1, 92=>1, 91=>0,90=>0,29=>1340,28=>1245,27=>1231,26=>1102,25=>937,24=>688, 23=>540, 22=>360, 21=>270, 20=>143, 19=>77,18=>62,17=>39, 16=>42, 15=>27, 14=>12, 13=>4, 12=>2, 11=>2}
```

and i want result of

```
arr = {9 => sum values of Nineties, 2 => sum values of twenties, 1 =>  sum values of age teens}
```

Comment: Why is your hash called `arr`?

Comment: `Array` and `Hash` are two very different types of object. Don't get confused between them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) method.
`(key, value)` here is a deconstruction of each key/value pair like `93=>1`, `hash` is an intermediate object to store the result.

```rb
data.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), hash|
  result_key = 
      case key
      when 10..19 then 1
      when 20..29 then 2
      when 90..99 then 9
      end
  next if result_key.nil?    
  hash[result_key] ||= 0
  hash[result_key] += value    
end
```

For the provided input I got `{9=>2, 2=>7856, 1=>267}`

**UPD**

A shorter solution suggested by Holger Just and Stefan in the comments below.

```rb
data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(key, value), hash|
  hash[key / 10] += value
end
```

With `Hash.new(0)` the initial object will be a hash with the default value `0`

```rb
> hash = Hash.new(0)
=> {}
> hash[1]
=> 0
```

Comment: You could just use `result_key = key / 10`.

Comment: In fact, if you change the initial object from `{}` to `Hash.new(0)` the whole block can be reduced to `hash[key / 10] += value`

Comment: For the given input yes